# How to validate Helm values that are not present in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**Input**

I'm writing a helm chart containing following values.yaml:

```
backend:
  container:
    resources: {}
  hpa:
    enabled: false
    targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

Then in a template file a deployment definition looks like:

```
template:
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: "some-name"
        image: "some-repo/some-image:latest"
        resources:
          {{- toYaml .Values.backend.container.resources | nindent 12 }}
```

**Problem**

On default I disable the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (*backend.hpa.enabled=false*), but if user enables it, I want to be sure that property *backend.container.resources.requests.cpu* is specified. Otherwise HPA wouldn't work. So I would like to throw exception in that case. How to implement such a validation check?

**Attempt 1**

I tried to write HPA template in following wrapper:

```
{{- if .Values.backend.hpa.enabled -}}
{{- if required "Specify requests!" .Values.backend.container.resources.requests.cpu -}}
...
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

But it throws nil exception on parsing template when *backend.container.resources.requests.cpu* is not specified (even if *backend.hpa.enabled=false*).

**Attempt 2**

If I replace values.yaml with the following fragment, then kubernetes will not allow to set such cpu value (illegal format, null is invalid too). Is that something that I can assign to a cpu field, that will be considered as default value in kubernetes? I think it could be not very elegant, but feasible solution.

```
backend:
  container:
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: ""
  hpa:
    enabled: false
    targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Helm 3 you can use JSON Schema Validation, you can read about it [here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#schema-files). You can use the [IF condition there](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#applying-subschemas-conditionally).

I wouldn't try to make the validation in the chart itself, because it will make your helm chart more complex.